NextJS Page To App Router Conversion Dilemma
I'm working on a website contact us form which works using the NextJS pages router, but returns null for the form fields with the app router. The code is based upon a tutorial which uses the pages router successfully. This is my first stackoverflow question and any help would be much appreciated.
Error:
When I run the app router version, the VSCode terminal displays: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName') at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/contactForm/route.ts:21:18)
The Chrome console displays: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) **and** Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at submitContactForm (useContactForm.ts:78:32)
What I've Tried:
My inquiry to the tutorial author has gone answered.
I've restructured the code into server and client components and made code changes to the best of my understanding. However, every code permutation I've tried over the last three weeks has created a conflict between server and client components.
Code Demo:
I can't put a demo online, because the backend uses security credentials. However, the backend setup works fine using the page router version. I'm running the code using the VSCode server and presume there is no CORS issue with the app router.
IDE
I'm using Visual Studio Code Version 1.88.0.
Related App Setup:
dependencies
    "isomorphic-fetch"
    "next": "14.1.4"
    "next-intl": "^3.11.1"
    "react": "^18"
    "react-dom": "^18"

devDependencies
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.0"
    "@types/node": "^20"
    "@types/react": "^18"
    "@types/react-dom": "^18"
    "eslint": "^8"
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.4"
    "typescript": "^5"

File Structure:
Email/page.tsx (server component) (src/app[locale]))
EmailClient.tsx (client component) (src/components))
route.ts (POST function) (src/app/api/contactForm))
useContactForm.ts (hook) (/hooks))
useForm.ts (hook) (/hooks))
config.ts (/src)
global.d.ts (/)
tsconfig.json (/) (..."src/global.d.ts")

Code:
Email.tsx
import { Box, Card, CardContent, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages } from "next-intl";
import pick from "lodash/pick";
import styles from "@/src/styles/Email.module.css";
import EmailClient from "@/src/components/EmailClient";
import { unstable_setRequestLocale } from "next-intl/server";

import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

type Props = {
  params: { locale: string };
};

export default function Email({ params: { locale } }: Props) {
  unstable_setRequestLocale(locale);

  const t = useTranslations("common");
  const t_email = useTranslations("page.email");
  const useContactFormErrorPrefix = t_email("Oops!TheField:");
  const useContactFormErrorSuffix = t_email("Is-Empty-Retry");

  let messages = useMessages();

  return (
    <Box id={styles.gridContainer}>
      <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
        {t("Contact-Us")}
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        variant="body2"
        color="textSecondary"
        marginBottom="0.5rem"
        component="p"
      >
        {t_email("Email-Instructions")}
      </Typography>
      {/* In order to avoid an 'Invalid prop children supplied to... expected a ReactNode' in the client components of this server component, it is necessary to wrap NextIntlClientProvider in a div. (An MUI Box will not work. */}
      <div>
        <NextIntlClientProvider
          locale={locale}
          messages={pick(messages, "page.email")}
        >
          <Grid>
            <Card
              style={{ maxWidth: 450, margin: "0 auto", padding: "20px 5px" }}
            >
              <CardContent>
                <EmailClient/>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}

EmailClient.tsx
"use client";

import { Button, Grid, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import useContactForm from "@/hooks/useContactForm";
import useForm from "@/hooks/useForm";
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

export default function EmailClient() {
  const t_email = useTranslations("page.email");

  const { values, updateValue, resetValues } = useForm({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
  });
  const { firstName, lastName, email, subject, message } = values;
  const { loading, outputMessage, submitContactForm } = useContactForm({
    values,
    resetValues,
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitContactForm}>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid xs={12} sm={6} item>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            label={t_email("First-Name")}
            placeholder={t_email("Enter-First-Name")}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            name="firstName"
            id="firstName"
            onChange={updateValue}
            value={firstName}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} sm={6} item>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            label={t_email("Last-Name")}
            placeholder={t_email("Enter-Last-Name")}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            name="lastName"
            id="lastName"
            onChange={updateValue}
            value={lastName}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} item>
          <TextField
            type="email"
            label={t_email("Email")}
            placeholder={t_email("Enter-Email-Address")}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            name="email"
            id="email"
            onChange={updateValue}
            value={email}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} item>
          <TextField
            type="text"
            label={t_email("Email-Subject")}
            placeholder={t_email("Enter-Email-Subject")}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            name="subject"
            id="subject"
            onChange={updateValue}
            value={subject}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} item>
          <TextField
            label={t_email("Message")}
            multiline
            rows={7}
            placeholder={t_email("Enter-Email-Message")}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            required
            name="message"
            id="message"
            onChange={updateValue}
            value={message}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} item>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
            {loading ? t_email("Sending-Email") : t_email("Send-Email")}
          </Button>
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            gutterBottom
            color="textSecondary"
            component="p"
            sx={{ my: 1 }}
          >
            {outputMessage || t_email("Awaiting-Submission")}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}

route.ts
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

type TBodyFields = {
  [key: string]: string;
};

export async function POST(
  req: NextRequest) {

  const { body }: { body: TBodyFields } = await req.json();

  // Checking we have data from the email input
  const requiredFields = [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "email",
    "subject",
    "message",
  ];

  for (const field of requiredFields) {
    if (!body[field]) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: `Oops! You are missing the ${field} field, please fill it in and retry.` })
    }
  }

  // Setting vars for posting to API
  const endpoint = process.env.CONTACT_FORM_ENDPOINT;

  // posting to the API
  await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstName: body.firstName,
      lastName: body.lastName,
      email: body.email,
      subject: body.subject,
      message: body.message,
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-api-key": process.env.CONTACT_FORM_API_KEY,
      charset: "utf-8",
    },
  });
  
  return NextResponse.json({
      message: "Success! Thank you for your message!"},
    { status: 200 }
  );
}

useContactForm.ts
'use client'

import { SyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
import { server } from "@/src/config";
import { ContactFormValues } from "@/types";

type Props = {
  values: ContactFormValues;
  resetValues: () => void;
}

type Output = {
  message: string;
};

/*
useContactForm handles the submission of the form to the Next.js API route, the response from the API route, the error and loading states seen in the UI.
*/
export default function useContactForm({values, resetValues }: Props) {
  // Setting state to be returned depending on the outcome of the submission.
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [outputMessage, setOutputMessage] = useState<string | null>("");
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean | null>();

  // destructuring out the values from values passed to this form.
  const { firstName, lastName, email, subject, message } = values;

  async function submitContactForm(e: SyntheticEvent) {
    // Prevent default function of the form submit and set state to defaults for each new submit.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set base state
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    setOutputMessage(null);

    // gathering data to be submitted to the serverless function
    const body = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      subject,
      message,
    };

    const requiredFields = [
      "firstName",
      "lastName",
      "email",
      "subject",
      "message",
    ];

    // Checking required fields aren't empty.
    for (const field of requiredFields) {
      if (!field?.length) {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
        setOutputMessage(
          `Oops! The field: ${field} is empty, please fill it in and retry.`
        );
        return;
      }
    }

    // Send the data to the serverless function on submit.
    const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/contactForm`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });

    const responseText: string = await res.text();

    // Waiting for the output of the serverless function and storing into the serverlessBaseoutput var.
    const output = (await JSON.parse(responseText)) as Output;

    // check if successful or if was an error
    if (res.status >= 400 && res.status < 600) {
      // Oh no there was an error! Set to state to show user
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
      setOutputMessage(output.message);
    } else {
      // everything worked successfully.
      setLoading(false);
      setOutputMessage(output.message);
      resetValues();
    }
  }

  return {
    error,
    loading,
    outputMessage,
    submitContactForm,
  };
}

useForm.ts
'use client'

import { useState } from "react";
import { ContactFormValues } from "@/types";

type UpdateProps = {
  target: {
    value: string;
    name: string;
  };
};

export type UseFormUpdateValues = ({
  target: { value, name },
}: UpdateProps) => void;

interface ReturnProps {
  values: ContactFormValues;
  updateValue: UseFormUpdateValues;
  resetValues: () => void;
}

/*
useForm handles the storing and updating of values used in the from prior to submission. This means when we submit the form, we can take the values stored in the state of this hook as the values for the request to the API.
*/
export default function useForm(defaults: ContactFormValues): ReturnProps {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(defaults);

  function updateValue({ target: { value, name } }: UpdateProps) {
    // Set the value by spreading in the existing values and changing the key to the new value or adding it if not previously present.
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  function resetValues() {
    setValues(defaults);
  }

  return { values, updateValue, resetValues };
}

config.ts
import {Pathnames} from 'next-intl/navigation';
export const locales = ["en"] as const;
export const pathnames = {...} satisfies Pathnames<typeof locales>;
export const localePrefix = 'always';
export type AppPathnames = keyof typeof pathnames;
export const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
export const server = dev ? "http://localhost:3000" : "https://....com";

global.d.ts
/*
Typescript uses this file to determine that data in the global.d.ts file is of type string.
Doing this prevents 'any' or 'unknown' linting errors.  This file must be included in tsconfig.json's
includes array
*/

import { ContactFormValues } from "@/types";
import { NextRequest as OriginalNextRequest } from "next/server";

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      (backend security data here)
    }
  }
  interface NextRequest extends OriginalNextRequest {
    body: ContactFormValues;
  }
}
  
  export {};

